# What is the best way to "rename" a Rust `std::iter::Iterator` function for my own library?

Tags: rust, rust-itertools

I am trying to rename the `std::iter::Iterator::scan` function in a Itertools like library of my own.

```rs
    // A renaming of https://doc.rust-lang.org/src/core/iter/traits/iterator.rs.html#1420
    fn scan_while<St, B, F>(self, initial_state: St, f: F) -> Scan<Self, St, F>
    where
        Self: Sized,
        F: FnMut(&mut St, Self::Item) -> Option<B>,
    {
        Scan::new(self, initial_state, f)
    }
```

However, I get the error:

```
    // 42 |         Scan::new(self, initial_state, f)
    //    |               ^^^ private associated function
```

What is the idiomatic Rust way to do something like this?

(please don't say "don't rename it")

Comment: Wouldn't `Self` have to have the `Iterator` trait? Then you would return `self.scan(...)`.

Answer (score 0):

As caTS mentioned, the solution is:

```rs
    fn scan_while<St, B, F>(self, initial_state: St, f: F) -> Scan<Self, St, F>
    where
        Self: Sized,
        F: FnMut(&mut St, Self::Item) -> Option<B>,
    {
        self.scan(initial_state, f)
    }
```